# TRUE/FALSE: Function f is integrable on [a, b] provided that f is uniformly continuous on [a, b]

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration

Statement: "TRUE/FALSE: Function f is integrable on [a, b] provided that f is uniformly continuous on [a, b]"

I'm not sure if I understand what "provided that" means. Does this mean that the proof would work either way? Is it the same as saying "A function f on [a, b] which is uniformly continuous is Riemann integrable on [a, b]."

Comment: It means that if a function is uniformly continuous on the closed interval, it is integrable (as you said in your last sentence).

Comment: “Provided” is an “if.”

Answer (score 1):

Uniformly continuous implies bounded implies (with continuity) integrable.  The reverse is not true.  Discontinuous functions may be integrable.